# Creating a simple file using Rapture.io in scala

Tags: scala, file-io, rapture.io

I'm trying to run a very simple example using [Rapture.io](http://rapture.io/). Not sure what I'm missing here?

```
scala> import rapture.io._
import rapture.io._

scala> import rapture.core._
import rapture.core._

scala> val x = File / "tmp" / "a.txt"
<console>:20: error: value / is not a member of object java.io.File
       val x = File / "tmp" / "a.txt"
                    ^

scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> val x = File / "tmp" / "a.txt"
<console>:21: error: value / is not a member of object java.io.File
       val x = File / "tmp" / "a.txt"
                    ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include following dependency in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "com.propensive" %% "rapture-fs" % "0.9.1"
```

Where the version number (i.e. `0.9.1`) should reflect the one currently available, which usually corresponds to the version of `rapture-core` you're using

Then, in the source code

```
import rapture.fs._
```

Do not import java.io.File. Otherwise it will create ambiguity.

See this link for more info.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rapture-users/N3-wIBKuNaA